# I want to plot the integral of sin(x^2) in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

i want to plot the integral of y=sin(x^2) in pgfplots but dont know what to put inside 
the ''{ }''. This is because its a prety hard function to integrate. Can someone help me!

Comment: You might be better off with Asymptote/PSTricks for this.

Comment: @Jubobs. According to wolframalpha the integral of sin(x^2) is sqrt(π/2) FresnelS(sqrt(2/π) x). It gives a plot  in wolfram but i cant take the function and put it into pgfplots

Comment: Pgfplots comes without numerical integration schemes.
But since you already managed to plot your function in some external tool, you could sample the function and plot that data file in pgfplots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

run with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-3)(4.5,3)
\psaxes[ticksize=0 4pt, subticks=5](0,0)(-4.4,-2.5)(4,2.5)
\psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=5000,linecolor=red]{-4}{4}{sin(x*x)}
\psCumIntegral[plotpoints=10000,Simpson=10,linecolor=blue]{0}{4}{ dup mul RadtoDeg sin }
\psCumIntegral[plotpoints=10000,Simpson=10,linecolor=blue]{0}{-4}{ dup mul RadtoDeg sin }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a question about your code but please bear in mind that I'm an absolute ignorant of `pstricks` (and most of other latex packages for that matter). Why have you plotted the integral in two separate domains (i.e. [-4,0] and [0,4]) instead of [-4,4]?

Comment: With that numerical integration it does nothing else than adding the area under the function with Simpson's rule. It is not the mathematical solution of `\int sin x^2 dx`, which can be seen at mathworld.com. The integral must be symmetrical: `F(x)=-F(-x)` that's the reason why I plot it from the origin to the left and to the right.

Comment: [I see what you did there!](http://static2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130925101957/powerlisting/images/a/a9/I-see-what-you-did-there.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Seems indeed also reasonably easy to obtain with Asymptote. Following Herbert's inspired lead:

```
import graph;
// Unit
unitsize(2cm);
// Axis lengths
real xmin = -4, xmax = 4.25;
real ymin = -1.5, ymax = 1.5;
// The sin(x^2) function
real f(real x) {return sin(x^2);};
// Its integration (via the Simpson algorithm)
real g(real x) {return simpson(f, 0, x);};
// The curves
draw(graph(f, -4, 4, n = 1600, operator ..), red);
draw(graph(g, -4, 4, n = 1600, operator ..), blue);
// Axes
xaxis(xmin, xmax, Ticks(Step=1, step=0.2,  OmitTick(0)));
yaxis(ymin, ymax, Ticks(Step=1, step=0.2,  OmitTick(0)));
label("$O$", (0,0), 1.1SW);
```

If saved as, for example, `fresnel.asy`, you can process this code with the command line

```
asy -f pdf -V fresnel.asy
```

to obtain a PDF file and view it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can get that plot shown by Wolfram Alpha into pgfplots (and other complicated functions) by using the `sagetex` package. This gives you access to the free CAS system which can do the calculations of the value which then are typeset into into LaTeX. The y_coords array gets all the calculations of the integral and then all of the points (x_coords, y_coords) are typeset (by sage) into tikzpicture commands which are finally output into your tex document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
x=var('x')
t = var('t')
x_coords = [t for t in srange(-4.0,4.0,.01)]
y_coords = [numerical_integral(sin(x^2), 0, t)[0] for t in    srange(-4.0,4.0,.01)]
output = ""
output += r"\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]"
output += r"\begin{axis}[xmin=-4.0, xmax=4.0, ymin=-1.2, ymax=1.2,]"
output += r"\addplot[thin,blue] coordinates {"

for i in range(0,len(x_coords)):
    output += r"(%f, %f) "%(x_coords[i],y_coords[i])

output += r"};"
output += r"\end{axis}"
output += r"\end{tikzpicture}"
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result of the code running in Sagemath Cloud:
[image]