# Using SageTeX with siunitx

Tags: macros, siunitx, sagetex

I have the following problem: I'd like to do calculations using SageTeX and use the result in an `siunitx` expression, so that (for example)

```
\SI{\sage{3.5^2}}{kg m}
```

would give me the same result as

```
\SI{12.25}{kg m}
```

However, due to how SageTeX works, it's not as easy as this. Trying to compile the following document:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{sagetex}

\begin{document}

\SI{\sage{3.5^2}}{kg m}

\end{document}
```

Gives me this:

```
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode test.tex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 9 languages loaded.

...

No file test.sagetex.sout.
)
No file test.aux.

...

! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.8 \SI{\sage{3.5^2}}{kg m}

Runaway argument?
{\def \@currenvir {NoHyper}\edef \@currenvline {\on@line }\csname NoH\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \reserved@a was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.8 \SI{\sage{3.5^2}}{kg m}


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-number"
! 
! Invalid token '\immediate ' in numerical input.
! 
! See the siunitx documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.8 \SI{\sage{3.5^2}}{kg m}

! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.8 \SI{\sage{3.5^2}}{kg m}

Runaway argument?
{\def \@currenvir {NoHyper}\edef \@currenvline {\on@line }\csname NoH\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \reserved@a was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.8 \SI{\sage{3.5^2}}{kg m}


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! siunitx error: "invalid-number"
! 
! Invalid numerical input '\immediate \write \ST@sf {try:
 _st_.inline(0,
! latex(3.5^2))
except:
 _st_.goboom(8)}\def \par '.
! 
! See the siunitx documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.8 \SI{\sage{3.5^2}}{kg m}

*********************************************************************
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux) )
(\end occurred when \iffalse on line 8 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \iffalse on line 8 was incomplete)
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/share/texlive/texmf-d
ist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 8198 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Unfortunately, I don't understand (La)TeX's internals well enough to decide whether there is a feasible solution to this. Is it possible to work around this somehow in LaTeX, or would it be better to try to program something in Sage itself?

Comment: I don't have `sage` so cant test it, but as this works with `pgf` math, you could try saving the computation in a variable and then using it: `\pgfmathsetmacro{\Value}{3.5^2}` and then
`\SI{\Value}{\kilo\gram\meter}`.  If you are interested in a non-sage answer let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately, pgf seems to work quite differently than the `SageTeX` package (pgf is pure TeX, after all). While your example using pgf does indeed work, something like `\pgfmathsetmacro{\Value}{\sage{3.5^2}}` (same error as above) or `\NewDocumentCommand{\Value}{}{\sage{3.5^2}}
\SI{\Value}{kg m}` does not (error: "Invalid token '\Value ' in numerical input \SI{\Value}{kg m}"). I want to use Sage specifically because the actual computations are much more complicated than the example in the question and involve some Sage (Python) code.

Comment: If you just print `\Value` do you get a numerical output?

Comment: Well, yes, but of course, I first have to run Sage on the generated `.sage` file, and then I have to run `pdflatex` again, since SageTeX (as far as I understand) uses references to insert its computed results.

Comment: A solution that works with PythonTeX is [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122004/10742). Since PythonTeX operates in a manner similar to SageTeX, I expect a similar or even almost identical solution may be possible.  But I don't have Sage to test this.

Comment: Here is a feature request for sagetex: https://github.com/dandrake/sagetex/issues/2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everyone can get access to Sage with [Sagemath Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com); no installation necessay. I've found that the way around the problems of not working when combined with other packages is to do the calculations in `sagesilent` mode and then create the text that gets inserted into your document (see for example, my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161664/i-want-to-plot-the-integral-of-sinx2-in-pgfplots/161735#161735)). I still found an issue with the output giving me too many digits, even when I specified how many I wanted. Converting it to a string gave me control over the format. I'm no expert in `sagetex` so maybe there's a better way, but the code works.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
answer = 4.5^2
output1 = r"\SI{%f}{kg m}"%(answer.n(digits=4))
output2 = r"\SI{%s}{kg m}"%(str(answer.n(digits=4)))
\end{sagesilent}
Output without using a string:
\sagestr{output1}

Output using a string:
\sagestr{output2}
\end{document}
```

Here's the code running in SageMathCloud:
[image]

Comment: Oh, that's just perfect! I didn't realize that text output by `\sagestr{}` would not only be pasted verbatim into the document, but also evaluated by LaTeX! That's great, thank you very much!

Comment: Note: SageMathCloud changed name, and is now CoCalc: https://cocalc.com.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could take a look at [my relevant question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/578613/2288).