# Truncates the value to two decimal places

Tags: sagetex

Suppose you want to print pi with 2 decimal digits. The following code does not work

```
$\sage{"%0.2f"%pi}$
```

What should be used instead?

Comment: in which way it doesn't work in terms of making the question clearer?

Comment: I get error when I latex the source. Probably the character % is interpreted as a comment by the latex compiler.

Comment: Does this `$\sage{"\%0.2f"\%pi}$` work maybe by escaping the percent chars? If this is Python then maybe you can also use the new string formatting `$\sage{'{0:.2f}'.format(pi)}$`

Comment: @PrimoPetri You are getting answers which use non-`sagetex` methods e.g. using Lua or PGF. I think if you could make it more obvious that you want a `sagetex` solution, that would be helpful. The 'What should be used instead?' is being understood as 'I'm open to non-`sagetex` solutions'. Alternatively, if you are open to such solutions, of course make that clear instead.

Comment: This is presumably calling SAGE from pdflatex (or whatever you use to process your file), and that isn't allowed by default (for security reasons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DJP's answer is good; I will add that "`pi`" in Sage is *not* a float; it is a (Sage/Python) object that represents the real number pi.

You did not describe the error, but I believe what is going wrong is that LaTeX is interpreting the `%` as a comment character. There is a way to use your string formatting method, but the idiomatic way to get 
a decimal approximation in Sage is to use the `.n()` method. Here are some examples:

`$\sage{pi.n()}$`

`$\sage{pi.n(10)}$` which returns an approximation with 10 *bits* of accuracy

`$\sage{pi.n(digits=10)}$` which returns an approximation accurate to 10 significant figures

`$\sage{pi.n(digits=10000)}$` if you want to fill several screens full of digits

If you use Sage, you really should get used to using `.n()` on various things. Open a worksheet on [SageMathCloud](http://cloud.sagemath.com) and try it on things like `pi`, `sqrt(5)`, `e`, `log(123)`, and so on. Also feel free to ask questions on the psage-support Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sage-support).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\noindent Print $\pi$ as a number: $\sage{pi.n(digits=3)}$\\
Print $\pi$ as a string: \sagestr{str(pi.n(digits=3))}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output in Sagemath Cloud:
[image]

As I mention [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175745/using-sagetex-with-siunitx/175759#175759) there are issues with digits and using `sage` that I don't understand. Using `sagestr` has been better for me.

Answer (score 1):

Can this help?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro \pi {pi}

\node at (0,0) {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pi}};
\node at (0,-1) {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=4]{\pi}};
\node at (0,-2) {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=6]{\pi}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe that the OP wants to know what to use in `sagetex` rather than asking about an entirely different method. You are the second person to offer an answer of this kind so I think maybe the question should be clarified.

Comment: Sorry about that. Didnt notice. Perhaps someone else searching for a similar answer might find my contribution useful.