# Handling the numerical output of SageTeX with siunitx

Tags: siunitx, sagetex

Which one of the three methods below is correct to handle the numerical output of sagetex with `siunitx`? and how to do it correctly?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex,siunitx,mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{sagesilent}
        from sage.calculus.calculus import at
        f(x) = exp(x) * sin(2*x)
        out1 = r"\num{%f}"%(numerical_approx(diff(f(x),x,2).subs(x=2))
        out2 = numerical_approx(diff(f(x),x,2).subs(x=2))
    \end{sagesilent}
    %\num[round-precision=2]{numerical_approx(diff(f(x),x,2).subs(x=2)} or 
    \sagestr{out1} or 
    %\num[round-precision=3]{out2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the 3 approaches you've given, only  `\sagestr{out1}` has a chance of working. That's because it's a 3 step compilation process: first run is LaTeX **and this must compile without error**, second is Sage, 3rd is LaTeX substituting Sage results into LaTeX code. The part in bold explains why the other 2 approaches won't work as is (possible with `expl3` code, I would think, given some previous questions where it popped up. See frougon's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543396/how-to-execute-sagetex-code-multiple-times-with-loop/543469#543469) for example). First time through the LaTeX code and it is given `\num[round-precision=2]{numerical_approx(diff(f(x),x,2).subs(x=2)}` it will throw an error because Sage hasn't run so trying to run LaTeX on it is useless. Same with `\num[round-precision=3]{out2}`. Sage hasn't run on `sagesilent` so now you're trying to process out2 which is not a number. With the code as given the first time through with LaTeX and the document is empty. Second pass through Sage runs and `out1 = r"\num{%f}"%(numerical_approx(diff(f(x),x,2).subs(x=2))` is calculated. Third pass through and `sagestr` is processed, gets the string represented by `out1` and typesets it. Since you've loaded the `siunitx` package, it compiles without an error. What doesn't make sense to me is going to `siunitx` to format your number when it can be done without it. This opens up the possibility of having a number in Sage, such as 4.2499999995, get put into a `\num` as 4.25 and getting rounded up to 4.3. You can handle number formatting with just Sage.

Here is a modification of your code to illustrate some possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex,siunitx,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
    from sage.calculus.calculus import at
    f(x) = exp(x)*sin(2*x)
    out = r"%f"%(n(diff(f(x),x,2).subs(x=2)))
    out1 = r"%4.2f"%(n(diff(f(x),x,2).subs(x=2))) 
    out2 = r"%f"%(n(diff(f(x),x,2).subs(x=2),digits=5))
    out3 = r"\num{%f}"%(n(diff(f(x),x,2).subs(x=2)))
\end{sagesilent}
\noindent    \sagestr{out} is the number with all its float digits or\\
\sagestr{out1} is the number with least 4 spaces, 2 digits for the decimal or\\ 
\sagestr{out2} there are 5 significant digits for float length number or\\
\sagestr{out3} puts the full float into macro for processing.
\end{document}
```

The output from Cocalc is:
[image]

Try changing `out1 = "%4.2f"%(n(diff(f(x),x,2).subs(x=2)))f"%(n(diff(f(x),x,2).subs(x=2)))` to `out1 = r"%4.4f"%(n(diff(f(x),x,2).subs(x=2)))` and you'll see that the number is rounded up. In `%4.2f` a number like 1/2 will become .50 (taking up 3 spaces) and an extra space will be put in front. This can be used as in my [Trig Table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219774/showcase-of-programming-your-document-paradigm/219789#219789) to get alignment of  the data.

**EDIT:** Two things I forgot to mention. The first is that `n()` is an equivalent version of `numerical_approximation()`. See [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/misc/sage/misc/functional.html) in the documentation (near the top). The second is to address the error in your code. When I run it in Cocalc I see:
[image]

The error tells me it's related to the line `out2 = numerical_approx(diff(f(x),x,2).subs(x=2))` and since the `^` points to the beginning I suspect the line before that. When I click at the end of the line it shows me, in green, that the last `)` matches up with `(` from `(diff`. That means you're missing a parenthesis to match up with `(` from `(num`. Change your code to `out1 = r"\num{%f}"%(numerical_approx(diff(f(x),x,2).subs(x=2)))` and it will run.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I am away from PC to experiment but \num is just for testing since the real deal is to append the number with unit. I will take some time to go through it then get back in case of any inquiries.

Comment: May I know why this line in my question doesn't work? `out1 = r"\num{%f}"%(numerical_approx(diff(f(x),x,2).subs(x=2))`

Comment: I've added detail on that at the end of my answer. You are missing a parenthesis `)` at the end.